# Number of solutions to pentagonal-pentagonal numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Continuing the investigation from [*this question*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67302/pentagonal-numbers-made-from-pentagonal-numbers) on CGSE about *pentagonal-pentagonal* numbers:

Defining $p(n)$ as the $n$th pentagonal number (a positive integer of the form $n(3n−1)/2,\ n\geq 1$), and $pp(n)$ as the $n$th *pentagonal-pentagonal* number, where $pp(n)$ is the smallest pentagonal number which is also the sum of $n$ consecutive pentagonal numbers (if it exists), we have

$$pp(n)=\sum_{i=N}^{N+n-1}p(i)$$

Letting the definition of $pp(n)$ be the smallest solution for the above sum, gives, for example,

$$pp(4)=5+12+22+35=330$$

However, there is no solution for $pp(3)$.

The solutions get large quickly, as obviously $pp(n)\geq n(n-1)^2/2$, but are often *much* larger.

*eg* the smallest solution for $$pp(926)=68861900859697184438810992296964899584575857208833324126$$

Defining

\begin{equation}
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
&1 \quad \text{ if }pp(n)\text{ has a solution}\\
&0 \quad \text{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$ is then the counting function for the number of $pp(n)$ with a solution $\leq n$.

The following are the values I got for $f(n),\ 1\leq n\leq 1000$:

```
pp={1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1};
```

Clearly, there are an infinite number of $pp(n)$ with solutions, since  $$pp(3 n (n+1)+1)=3 (n+1) (3 n (n+1)+1) ((n+1) (3 n (n+1)+1)+1)$$

I am guessing from calculations that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\sim \dfrac{n}{\log\log n +1/5}$$

Is this the case? If not, what is the asymptotic density of $f(n)$ in $\mathbb{N}$?

Can this be generalised to other polygonal numbers?

Comment: Can you fix your definition of $pp(n)$? Your question will clearly make sense at some point, but currently I can make neither head nor tail of any of your definitions of $pp(n)$.

Comment: Oh -- the definition (from the link in the question) is this: "$pp(n)$ is the smallest pentagonal number which is also the sum of $n$ consecutive pentagonal numbers, if it exists". Here a pentagonal number appears by definition to be positive, and so is a number of the form $(3n^2-n)/2$ for an integer $n>=1$.

Comment: I would be slightly surprised if your computations of $f(n)$ are 100% accurate: I'm assuming you're just searching up to a certain range and then giving up. These are generalised Pell equations and solving them when $n$ is large will involve some subtleties I suspect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the assertion that clearly there are infinitely many $n$ such that $pp(n)$ exists?

Comment: What does $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N}^{i + n}$ mean?  Is it meant to be $\sum_{i = 1}^n$?

Comment: @L.Spice No, it could be any $n$. Apologies if non-standard. $i+n$ means $n$ consecutive pentagonal numbers after $p(i)$. I am open to suggestions to reword.

Comment: The definition you have right now is the some of $n+1$ consecutive pentagonal numbers.  Change the limits in your sum to $\sum_{i=N}^{N+n-1}$.

Comment: An easier but still challenging problem:  How does one algorithmically determine whether $f(n)$ is one.  For any given $n$ you can come up with clever tricks (for example, I can see proving that no sum of 3 consecutive penta's is a penta) but in general, what is the test?

Comment: @Mark Fischler: you are just asking for an algorithm for solving a generalised Pell equation, so you need algorithms for units of, and factorizations of ideals in, an order in a quadratic field.

Comment: How are pentagonal numbers defined? Unlike triangles and squares, pentagons give different results when you put in negative numbers for the argument, thus $p(0)=1$ and $p(1)=5$ but there is also $p(-1)=2$. How does this affect your problem?